# How to insert into table from another table using conditional select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have `UCP` table and `SalesPerProduct` which contained data 
I want to insert into `SalesPerProduct` From  `UCP` Conditional select
When i do select it works fine i used this query

```
select t.ID, sum(Qty) as sum_BioxellTerritories , 
sum(SalesResult) as Sales , BioxellTerritories 
from UCP as t group by ID ,BioxellTerritories
ORDER BY BioxellTerritories ASC
```

when I Used insert

```
insert into SalesPerProduct 
(ProductID , Volume , Sales ,Territories )values
select t.ID, sum(Qty) as sum_BioxellTerritories , sum(SalesResult) 
as Sales , BioxellTerritories from UCP as t group by ID ,BioxellTerritories   ORDER BY BioxellTerritories ASC
```

Didn't work for me .. for sample of data This is the result of select which I want to insert

[image]

Comment: what didn't work for you? did you get an error? you need to remove `order by` during `insert` and remove `values` (as you are using a `select`)

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: Oh, you don't need the word `values` there

Comment: ty :) works for me can u write ur answer to accept it u deserve it :)

Comment: The same answer has already been posted, feel free to select one of them :)

Comment: ty @LordBaconPants also vkp :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this reference for `INSERT INTO SELECT` statements:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

In short, you don't need the `VALUES` keyword when combining a `SELECT` statement with `INSERT INTO`.

If you still have problems I'd suggest posting your table definitions so people can help you further.

Answer (score 2):

You just want `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into SalesPerProduct (ProductID, Volume, Sales, Territories )
    select t.ID, sum(Qty) as sum_BioxellTerritories, sum(SalesResult) 
as Sales, BioxellTerritories
    from UCP as t
    group by ID, BioxellTerritories
    order by BioxellTerritories ASC ;
```

The `VALUES` keyword is unnecessary.

Comment: Also note as per this answer: always use a target column list with the `insert` statement